# UIButton could not always show

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I created a UIButton and added to my view:

```
btn=[[UIButton alloc] init];
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0,rect.size.height-52, 70, 52)];
btn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,13,16,0);
btn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(35,-42,0, 0);
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view.window addSubview:btn];

-(void)doEnable:(BOOL)enable{
    if(enable){
      [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [btn setTitle:@"enter" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [btn setHidden:NO];

    //    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_turn_button];
    }
    else{
      [btn setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [btn setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [btn setTitle:@"  " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      btn.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

In `WillDidAppear` in called the doEnable with YES and in `WillDidDisappear` with NO, Then when I enter the view, the button should show up at the bottom-left.

Weird thing is, Sometimes it can show up, sometimes it can't. But even it can not show up, it still can receive touch event, the `btnClicked` method is always called. Why?

Comment: try adding a breakpoint to your doEnable method and make sure that it is being called with YES and NO when entering and leaving the screen as you're expecting. Also adding the button to the view should be [self.view addSubview:btn], not to the window

Comment: The method doEnable is always being called with YES and I've also tried [self.view addSubview:btn], but still not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call doEnable method in viewDidAppear and viewDidDisappear as updating UI in viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear isn't guaranteed because your view might not be loaded yet.

Comment: Ok. Can you put sample project with error so that we can track it?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

> [self.view.window addSubview:btn];

To this:

> [self.view addSubview:btn];

Comment: try customize it when you create it. Then when u want to hide it from user use `[btn setHidden:YES]` and disable user interaction with: `[btn setEnabled:NO]`.

Comment: I had tried `setEnable` method but the issue have been the same. Now I have to destroy the button in `WillDidDisappear` and re-create it in `WillDidappear`.

Comment: I don't think this is a big deal. And i just wanted to say that there is no such method like `WillDidDisappear` and `WillDidDisappear` they are called `-(void)viewWillAppear` and `-(void)viewWillDisappear`

Comment: Sorry, typo error. I mean `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidDisappear`